# Newtonsoft.Json Deserialize issue using php 7.0 json_encode array string

Tags: c#, php, json

PHP code:

```
$arr_return = array('status' => true,'expire' => $SQLGetUserResult['ExpirationDate'],'vip' =>  boolval($SQLGetUserResult['Vip']),'agent'=>true,'exception'=>false);
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$arr_return));
```

returns:

```
{"result":{"status":true,"expire":"2017-08-30 00:00:00","vip":false,"agent":true,"exception":false}}
```

C# deserialize json class using json to CSharp

```
public class Result
{
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public bool agent { get; set; }
    public string expire { get; set; }
    public bool vip { get; set; }
    public bool exception { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialze

```
RootObject Ldata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
```

throws:

> **Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0.**

I don't know why throw this exception?

Edit:
**[[Fiddle - Link code demo]](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pyu6cI)**

Edit:
[image: web source]

i think this﻿ is not showing on code,string, blank string..
on result not  showing
[image: VS 2017]

### Work now

i try search keep google and i found some solution 
using notepad ++ php file encoding change to utf-8 no bom option
but login .php already utf-8(nobom)
so i keep trying and find required php not correctly encoding thanks !

Comment: Your fiddle returns `true`, without any exception !? as I expected ;).

Comment: Your example is working. Check if you have problem with the escaping in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (json.Substring(0, 1) != "{")
{
    json = json.Substring(json.IndexOf("{", StringComparison.Ordinal));
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

> Note: I think your json starts with some invisible characters.

Comment: Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: @Gohchi I think this happens because of PHP or at client-side, So; creating a proper fiddle that produces that json with additional character in PHP and asking a question with [Tag:PHP] may make some senses - the above code doesn't return that [Sample Filddle](https://ideone.com/aqMKdb) - ;)